# Changing button image onclick

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a button called button1 that I want changed to button2 after a click.

```
.button1 {
   background-image: url("example.com"); 
 }

.button2 {
  background-image: url("example2.com"); 
 }
```

The link looks like this:

```
  <%= link_to example_path do %>
  <div class="button1"></div>
  <% end %>
```

and the jquery looks like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.button1').click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass(".button2");
  });
 });
```

Nothing is happening though when I click it.

Comment: `.toggleClass( "button2" );` no need for the `.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the leading . in the toggleClass line:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.button1').click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass("button2"); //NOT .button2
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

here a better way to do it in CSS;

```
.button1 {
   background-image: url("example.com"); 
 }

.button1:active {
  background-image: url("example2.com"); 
 }
```

Comment: This just changes it while its being clicked but i wanted it changed after also. Sorry if i wasn't clear.

Comment: Provide more explanation on what this code is doing. Doing this will minimize the use of copying and pasting without understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Just so there's no conflict between the two classes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.button1').click(function(){
     $(this).removeClass("button1").addClass("button2");
   });
});
```

If you choose to go this route, I would recommend putting an identifier on the button that is not related to the class containing the background-image attribute.

```
<%= link_to example_path do %>
<div class="mybutton button1"></div>
<% end %>
```

then you could do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.mybutton').click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('button1 button2');
   });
});
```

Unless, of course, you do not want to be able to toggle the button back once you click it, in which case the first code sample in this post would suffice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just removing the '.' ended up doing what i needed though.